# UIPanGestureRecognizer not recognizing pan small movements(<3mm)

Tags: ios, uigesturerecognizer

I'm trying to use `UIPanGestureRecognizer` to drag something around the screen. The problem is that when trying the drag, the gesture isn't recognized until I moved a certain `amount(>3mm)` across the screen. If I tap & hold on my object and make small `movements(<3mm)` back and forth, it's not recognized as a pan gesture. There's not problem if I use `TouchesBegan` where it recognized immediate my tap & hold. Is there anyway around this or I'm forced to use `TouchesBegan?`.

Answer (score 2):

You can, alternatively, use a `UILongPressGestureRecognizer`, but set its `minimumPressDuration` to something very small and its `allowableMovement` to something very large. The long press gesture recognizer won't calculate `translationInView` for you, but that's not hard to do yourself, and the long press gesture recognizer is a continuous gesture recognizer, much like the pan gesture recognizer.

If this feels too kludgy, you always can make your own gesture recognizer, but a properly configured long press gesture recognizer might be adequate for your purposes.